# html 5 sse unable to pass data to angular data

Tags: angularjs, server-sent-events

I have been trying to pass my sse data in the angular's data but it just won't display. Here is how I tried:

(my view)

```
<body ng-app>
  <div ng:controller="Main">
    <ul>
      <li ng:repeat="item in items">
        name:{{item.name}},age:{{item.age}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

(angular script)

```
var source = new EventSource('/feedcontain/test');

function Main($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  source.addEventListener('right', function(e) {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.items.push(e.data);
     });
    },
  false);

 }
```

(/feedcontain/test)

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo "data: [{name:'john', age:23}, {name:'Mary', age:28}, {name:'Sean', age:28}] \n\n";
```

I wanted to display `name:john, age:23` but it returns empty. I am trying to create something after I change the data or add then it will push to angularjs. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the event is ever happening, you end with an `name:,age:` result. All you should do then is to `concat` instead of `push`ing, as you're receiving an array.

```js
$scope.items = $scope.items.concat(e.data);
```

Keep in mind that the `$scope.items` reference will change, what will not break Angular, but might breake any other references to it. If you need it to not change, use a `for` to `push` each element.

Comment: Thanks caiotoon. i tried the concat but seems unable to change it when it gets the update from it. =( then i try again but doesn't seem working. i saw some article about watch. could it be similar to concat?

Comment: Is the event firing? Did you put a `console.log` or `debugger` inside the handler? No, `$watch` is a way of watching for properties to change. `concat` is an array method to concatenate two arrays into one. `push` adds the entire array argument as one entry in the targeted array.